# How to disable scroll in tab bar?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tabs, android-tabs

i have a problem with tab bar.
I styled tab bar with three tab, each with an icon, the problem is that the tab bar becomes scrollable and I would like to fixed.

I tried to put this in the style of the tab bar

```
<style parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid" name="ActionBar.Solid.Customactionbar">
     <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
     <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
     <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
     <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">false</item>
     <item name="android:scrollbars">none</item>

    </style>


    <style parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView" name="ActionBarTabStyle.Customactionbar">
     <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
     <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">false</item>
     <item name="android:scrollbars">none</item>

     </style>
```

and in activity_main

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:isScrollContainer="false">>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp" 
            android:showDividers="none"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:isScrollContainer="false">
        </TabWidget>
```

but nothing.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use ViewPager -  you need

**CustomViewPager.java**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
    this.isPagingEnabled = b;
}
}
```

replace your ViewPager

**from**

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
```

**to**

```
   <CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />
```

in your Activity:

```
  CustomViewPager mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
  mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```